# How to get result from Google OAuth API if user close browser window?

Tags: c#, wpf, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I create WPF application which uses [Google API Client Library for .NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth).
Following the sample, I wrote the code below:

```
        var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            Secrets,
            new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly" },
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None,
            new FileDataStore(TokenStorageName)).Result;
```

Calling of *AuthorizeAsync* method opens new browser window/tab with login form.
Problem appears if user just close browser window or tab. I never get result of this call.

Can I some how handle this situation ?

Should I change source code of AuthorizeAsync(...) ?

Answer (score 2):

The only way I've managed to work around the bug is to add a timeout period like DalmTo suggested. It's not ideal but I haven't found another way round the issue.

To do this I used the following code:

```
            '/ Create a new threading task /'
            Dim objTask As Task(Of Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.UserCredential)

            '/ Call google auth process /'
            objTask = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(objSecrets, mobjScopes, "user", CancellationToken.None, objFileStore)

            '/ Wait 2 minutes for a response /'
            objTask.Wait(240000)

            '/ If time out period expired status will still be Waiting for Activation /'
            If objTask.Status <> Tasks.TaskStatus.WaitingForActivation Then
                '/ Return user credentials /'
                Return objTask.Result
            End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the client library.   [No time out on GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync?](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/530) only option currently is to create a timeout yourself.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I can't predict users expectations and can't predict what timeout would be reasonable.

Comment: I have been playing with a 2 minute wait. Anything longer then that and I will just ask them again.   I would share the code but I am not happy with it at this time.

Comment: Please could your clarify. Your add 2 minutes timeout to source code of google API and now want to prepare push request ?

Answer (score 0):

See [GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync() hangs if browser closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43136455/googlewebauthorizationbroker-authorizeasync-hangs-if-browser-closed)

It's not possible, in general, to detect the user closing the browser tab/window. And using a cancellationToken currently does not work, [#968](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/968) filed to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I stubled upon this thread. This is my solution:

```
            Stopwatch Tijd = new Stopwatch(); 
            UserCredential UserCredentials = null;
            Tijd.Start();
            Task<UserCredential> OAuthResponse = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GSecrets.Secrets, Scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("Google AanmeldToken", true));
            while (OAuthResponse.Status == TaskStatus.WaitingForActivation && Tijd.ElapsedMilliseconds > 30000) ; // wait for login or 30s time-out
            if (OAuthResponse.Status == TaskStatus.WaitingForActivation) // timed-out after 30s
                return "";
            Tijd.Stop();
```

(this is a piece of the code that returns the username in string.)