# GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync() hangs if browser closed

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm writing a C# desktop app that can copy its output to a users Google Drive. However when I try an authorise access to Google with GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync() if the user closes the authentication page in the browser the method never returns!

Even if I use a 30 sec cancellation token it never returns if the browser is closed.

```
public bool Authorise()
{
    _authorised = false;
    UserCredential credential = null;
    try
    {
        // here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(new TimeSpan(0,0,30));
        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = this.ClientId, ClientSecret = this.ClientSecret },
                                                                 Scopes,
                                                                 UserName,
                                                                 cts.Token,//CancellationToken.None,
                                                                 new FileDataStore(AppName)).Result;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return _authorised;
    }

    if ((credential != null) && (credential.Token.AccessToken != null))
    {

        Service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { HttpClientInitializer = credential, ApplicationName = AppName, });
        _authorised = true;
    }

    return _authorised;
}
```

How can I trap the user closing the browser window and stop my application hanging?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue in the Google .net Client library.

1. [GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync Hang when user closes browser](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/508)
2. [No time out on GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync?](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/530)

There is currently no workaround that I know of.   I recommend adding your name to the issues on the forum to encourage the team to address the issue.

Update: Its now on the list [GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker does not honour CancellationToken when waiting for browser response](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/968)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, in general, to detect when the user has closed the browser window/tab.
For example, if the user is already running their default browser, then [GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Src/Support/GoogleApis.Auth.PlatformServices_Shared/OAuth2/GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs) opens a new tab, this is not running in the process started in [LocalServerCodeReceiver](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Src/Support/GoogleApis.Auth.PlatformServices_Shared/OAuth2/LocalServerCodeReceiver.cs#L398). That new process terminates immediately.

However, currently the CancellationToken passed to GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync is not honoured whilst waiting for the auth response, meaning even trying to use a simple timeout doesn't work. [#968](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/968) filed to fix this.

Comment: I'm currently experiencing this issue, is there any known work round or a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it with `BackgroundWorker`.
If the browser has been closed, the `background_RunWorkerCompleted` will be fired.

Don't forget to use `FileDataStore`,
because you can't get the credential variable from `BackgroundWorker`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this issue by adding the API call to a different thread, this avoids the main application from hanging.  then add a time out or specific condition to close the thread